# How do you access the position of an Orchard content item in a list from a part driver Display method?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a content part that's included on a content type which is often displayed in a list.  I'd like to access the position in the list from my part driver.  Is this possible?  I see that there is a Position property on the shape metadata object.  But how do I get to the content item's shape metadata from a part driver Display method?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, the position property is for something else entirely. There is a couple of problems with that question. First, what shape's metadata do you want to access from your driver? "The content item's shape" is not a meaningful expression: shapes are typically per content part, not content item.

Unfortunately, the list shape is not keeping the index anywhere on the item shapes it renders, so you'll have to add it yourself. This could be done for example by overriding the List shape rendering and setting the index as a property of the inner shapes yourself. This article should get you started: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template